# Half-Bridge vs Buck Converter

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter

I have some confusion regarding the difference between half-bridge and buck converters. I thought they were inherently different structures (H-Bridge having a transformer) however in some places, I've seen the term 'half-bridge buck converter' used.

Can someone clarify to me the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An H-bridge is not a half-bridge. The 'H' in H-bridge is not shorthand for half-bridge. An H-bridge is formed with two half-bridges and to produce a circuit in the shape of an 'H'.

An H-bridge's only job is to allow you to take a single-polarity source and swap it's polarity across a load. That load can be a a motor, an electromagnet, a speaker, a transformer, whatever. It doesn't change the fact it is an H-bridge.

A half-bridge is two switches connected together between a power rail. It's job is to switch the node common to both switches to one rail or the other, or disconnect it from both.

A simple buck converter uses a high-side switch and a free-wheeling diode sharing a common node with the inductor.

You can increase the efficiency of a buck converter by replacing the free-wheeling diode with a low-side switch and controlling it appropriately. This removes the forward voltage drop of the free-wheeling diode. This forms a half-bridge with the high-side switch that was already there. Replacing the free-wheeling diode with a switch is also called "synchronous rectification".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZS2jJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Ah I see. In the half-bridge, the common node between the switches still isn't the output right? The output is after the inductor. Half-bridges are only step-downs as well?

Comment: Well, the common node of the half-bridge is the output of the half-bridge. Whether or not the output of the half-bridge is the same as the output of the overall circuit is a different matter. You can do a lot of stuff with half-bridges. I wouldn't generalize to step down only. A half-bridge on its own can't stepdown either without an inductor. It just connects a node to either GND, +V, or disconnects it.

Comment: Ohhh. So the two switches is what we are referring to as a half-bridge configuration and depending how we connect the inductor/capacitor, we can achieve a certain topology - buck, boost, etc. So when people say 'half-bridge buck converter', they really mean a synchronous buck converter with two FETs rather than a FET and a diode.

Comment: Yes. Correct...

Comment: Thank you very much! It all makes sense now!

Comment: And if you don't control the low side FET, you still have a buck convertor thanks to the MOSFET's body diode. Adding control improves efficiency.

Comment: @user_1818839 That would be a lot of current through the body diode? Doesn't that cause problems?

Comment: Body diode current ratings are usually similar to the FET's channel ratings. So it'll work ... but the greater voltage drop means more dissipation, and yes that can cause problems.

Comment: @jaurunjljgrtutkwcy I mean, you could. But if you do that you can get better results with a purpose designed diode rather than an uncontrolled MOSFET. Would be more useful for testing purposes where not everything is up and running yet.